# Firebase realtime database read operation - Only get part of document returned possible?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I realise this question is marked as a duplicate - but I think this question is more comprehensive and easier to understand, and therefore more likely to help others. (^__^)**

I have read about reading data from Firebase realtime database. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

What I have not found is any documentation on how to control what data gets returned from the read query.

Consider the following structure:

```
-users
  -EiYu7OWooToo6noo
    alias: "Kermit"
    createdAt: 1538330532000
    firstName: "Kermit"
    surName: "Frogman" 
    pictureURL: "/imgs/kermit.png"
    phonePrimary: "555-1234"
    email: "kermit@themuppetshow.com"
    -myBooks
      -A1234567890
        title: "Frogs 101"
      ...
```

Is there a way to tell Firebase realtime database to only return some of the document data?

This code returns the entire document:

```
var ref = db.ref(`users/${uid}`);

ref.once("value", (snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Would it be possible to only get a partial document, for example:

```
    {
      alias: "Kermit"
      firstName: "Kermit"
    }
```

My reasoning is that this would be a huge performance gain when reading large amount of data. But is it possible?

Comment: console.log(snapshot.val().alias + " " + snapshot.val().firstName);

Comment: Yes, that would filter the result but the entire document would still be returned from the query? I edited my question to be less ambiguous. Or did you mean I can specify what parts of the document I want returned from the query?

Comment: If you target this var ref = db.ref(`users/${uid}/alias`); you will get only the alias

Comment: True, thanks! That would mean two requests, right? 1. ref = db.ref(users/${uid}/alias); 2. ref = db.ref(users/${uid}/firstName);

Comment: yes but i'm not sure you will gain in performance with that.

Comment: Many thanks! I will consider restructuring my data to better meet my needs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't select a subset of child nodes for a query.  Every query at a node always fetches the entire contents of the node - all the children and their children.

If you want only a subset of children, you have to perform different queries for each one.  Alternatively, you can organize your data in such a way that commonly grouped fields are collected together at a particular node.